# Browser Close Event in angular with resultValue. How can I get the decision of the user?

Tags: angular

I want to get the "event" from the user after the pop-up "Are you sure you want to close the site". So which button he pressed.

If a user have unsaved data and want to close a tab, the pop up "Do you really want to close your tab" will stop the refresh or the closing. 
But I want to get the decision of the user. Because if he will leave the site I want to do a special database query f.e.. Is that possible?

```
// in component    
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
public beforeUnloadHander($event: any) {
    $event.returnValue = true;
}
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to saved changes if the user clicks ok to close the browser.

Comment: go through this blog https://medium.com/@amcdnl/angular-guards-more-than-security-c04be35adb00 you will understand more better way

Comment: Thank you :) I will check this.

Comment: Maybe I can do it, with the onclose event.

Comment: Or maybe simply the unload event